# Counting the number of points in a sliding range

Tags: python

I have a large sorted file with one number per line. I want to output the number of numbers in each range of some size. So for example taking the range to be 10 and the input as

```
1
4
34
37
42
48
53
```

The output should be `[2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1]`. This is the length of `[1,4], [4], [34,37,42], [37,42], [42,48], [48,53], [53]`.  I think this can be solved using `deque` but, mostly as a programming exercise and also to use less memory, I am trying to solve by opening the file twice and have two different pointers into the file. One to read in the next left hand end of a list and one to read in the new right hand ends.  So my code has

```
fin1 = open(file, 'r')
fin2 = open(file, 'r')
```

I think loop over fin1 and when the range gets too big, I read in more of fin2 until the range is small enough and continue stepping down fin1 and fin2.

However I can't get this to work. It seems to not like me to have two file handles open for the same file.  How can one do this?

Comment: Why is `[4, 34]` not one of your ranges?  I think I'm missing some criteria.

Comment: The last number minus the first has to be less than 10.

Comment: Why isn't `[1]` or `[34, 37]` in the output?

Comment: I'm not getting how your input maps to your output.

Comment: [1,4] is the largest list that meets the criterion starting at 1.  Likewise [34,37,42] is the largest list starting at 34.

Comment: Then what about `[53]`?

Comment: @roippi For every number in the input, make the largest list of successive elements so that the difference between the first and last is less than 10 and output its length.

Comment: Is the file really too large to read into memory?

Comment: You should use one file handle with wise use of peek, seek and tell.

Comment: You should probably re-title the question to one about file seeking, rather than about the counting algorithm.  I think you understand your algorithm-- your question is about how to handle the files.

Comment: @Erhart you don't have to store the whole file, just lists which not exceed you given range

Comment: @RomanPekar Yes that is the deque solution I think (which no one has gone for surprisingly). But you don't even need to store that much using two file pointers.

Comment: @Erhart yes, got it. My deque implementation is not the best one even. But I've added solution with two file handlers, check it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses `itertools.tee()` to simulate reading from handles, but only actually opening one:

```
from itertools import tee

def sliding_range(file, size):
    fin1, fin2 = tee(int(ln.strip()) for ln in open(file) if ln.strip())
    n = 1
    next(fin2)
    val2 = next(fin2)
    for val1 in fin1:
        while val2 is not None and val2 <= val1 + size:
            n += 1
            try:
                val2 = next(fin2)
            except StopIteration:
                val2 = None
                break
        yield n
        n -= 1
```

Example (with your example data copied to 'test.txt'):

```
>>> list(sliding_range('test.txt', 10))
[2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

Comment: This looks very clever, thank you.  The `tee` documentation says "This itertool may require significant auxiliary storage (depending on how much temporary data needs to be stored). " but I assume this won't be a problem here.

Comment: `tee` will consume more memory if one of the iterables is way ahead of the others, if they are both advancing relatively in step with each other this will not be a problem.  In this particular case the total number of elements stored in memory at a single time will be approximately the same as the largest element in the result (largest window that fits the range).

Comment: Thanks and your solution is great. However I don't understand why it needs to even store that much.  In principle you just need two file pointers don't you?

Comment: Yep, but your question seemed to indicate that creating two file pointers might be causing you problems, and this is more efficient in that it only does the conversion to integers once.  It should in theory work just as well if you split the top line into two separate `open()` calls.  You might also want to look into [`os.dup()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.dup).

Comment: Thanks again. I did have a problem with two file handles to the same file. It seems you need one file handle and two file pointers if I understand some of the other answers here correctly. Or maybe os.dup() but I have never used that.

Comment: How would you get the generator to output one number at a time? Calling next(slidingrange('test.txt', 10) isn't right of course.

Comment: You can loop over the generator: `for n in sliding_range('test.txt', 10): print n`, you can also create the generator and use `next()` directly, but it will raise a `StopIteration` when the iterator is exhausted so this should be in a try/except.  To do this you would first save the generator to a variable, for example `sr = sliding_range('test.txt', 10)` and then `next(sr)` to get the next value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation, there might be a better way to do it but this should work. I'm assuming the same input you posted in your question.

```
def ranges(n):
    f = open("tmp.txt")

    while True:
        i = f.tell()
        try:
            curr = int(f.readline().rstrip())
        except ValueError:
            break  # EOF

        j = f.tell()

        while True:
            k = f.tell()  # End of range location
            try:
                next = int(f.readline().rstrip())
            except ValueError:
                break  # EOF

            if next < n or (next - curr) < n:
                continue
            else:
                break

        f.seek(i)  # Go to beginning of range

        r = []
        while f.tell() < k:
            r.append(int(f.readline().strip()))
        print(r)

        f.seek(j)  # Go to line after beginning of range


>>> ranges(10)
[1, 4]
[4]
[34, 37, 42]
[42, 48]
[48, 53]
[53]
```

Comment: You are using a list (` numbers = `) .. so you *are* loading the complete file in the memory

Comment: Also you could use int(l.strip()), which is secure for unix-style line endings, too

Comment: check my answer, I'm not loading the whole data into memory

Comment: @TobSpr Thanks for pointing out `l.strip()`. @Erhar I've updated my answer so it doesn't read the whole file into memory and uses `f.tell()` and `f.seek()` to navigate the file instead.

Comment: Thank you. I only want to output the lengths of the lists so I don't think I ever need to create them.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** my previous implementation is deque solution (and not perfect one). Here's solution with 2 file pointers:

```
def sliding_ranges(filename=r"C:\Temp\data.txt", N=10):
    f1, f2 = open(filename), open(filename)
    k, res, i1, i2, r1, r2 = 1, [], 0, 0, 1, 1
    while True:
        while r2 and (not i2 or i2 - i1 < N):
            r2, k = f2.readline(), k + 1
            if r2: i2 = int(r2)

        while r1 and (not i1 or not r2 or i2 - i1 > N):
            r1, k = f1.readline(), k - 1
            if i1: res.append(k)
            if r1: i1 = int(r1)

        if not r1: break

    return res

    >>> sliding_ranges(r"C:\Temp\data.txt", 10)
    [2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

**PREVIOUS:** here's implementation with one pass. While you're traversing, you keep counting length of lists

```
f = open(r"d:\temp\data.txt")

d, res, N = [], {}, 10
for j in f:
    i = int(j)
    if i not in res: res[i] = 1
    for k, v in res.items():
        if i - k > N:
            d.append(v)
            del res[k]
        elif k != i:
            res[k] += 1 
d = d + [v for v in res.values()]
```

here's list of objects in each iteration

```
d []
res {}

d []
res {1: 1}

d []
res {1: 2, 4: 1}

d [2, 1]
res {34: 1}

d [2, 1]
res {34: 2, 37: 1}

d [2, 1]
res {34: 3, 42: 1, 37: 2}

d [2, 1, 3, 2]
res {42: 2, 48: 1}

d = [2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

Comment: You are loading the file in the memory .. but I think the OP wanted to load it streamed.

Comment: Thanks but I would like to avoid reading the data into memory if possible.

Comment: @Erhart I'm not reading the whole file, check edited solution. I've used list only for example as iterable

Comment: The nested for loop looks slow unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're doing it this way, but to answer your question (which is about file I/O not about counting values) you need one file handle and two file pointers.

Once you open the file with file handle `f`, `f.tell()` will tell you what your position is in the file, and `f.seek(pos)` will move the pointer back to a given position.

`f.seek(pos,how)` takes an optional second parameter that gives you some flexibility in how the seek is calculated (setting `how` to 0 seeks from the beginning of the file, 1 from the current position, 2 from the end).  This lets you use `pos` as an offset from the reference, rather than strictly from the beginning.

Comment: How do you that in python?